# How to create realistic splinters from wood in blender?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing

Creating some broken splinters using cell fracture addon is quite easy, but how do you create some realistic splinters that come from a broken wood?

Specifically, how to achieve [this specific kind of thing in blender](https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1763552/291251156/stock-photo-broken-small-piece-of-wood-on-black-background-291251156.jpg)?

Comment: have you seen [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/w_m81zF9WtY) ? What I would try to make it more realistic is to add more splinters, make them thinner and more scaled vertically, subdivide them in simple mode and use soft body physics to have them bend. May require quite some experimenting before getting a convincing result.

Comment: @Gamnamno, Yes I have checked out using the fracture addon and have checked out most of the tutorials on smashing and destructing. It turns out it uses some kind of voronoi algorithm that creates a bounding box around a mesh object and it applies it to the entire mesh, so once you hit apply it smashes the whole mesh and it gets convered into peices, hence one can't do further editing with it.

Comment: any kind of suggestion would be helpful

Comment: What kind of "further editing" are you talking about ?

Comment: @Gamnamno, after adding the cell fracture to the mesh, the whole mesh is shattered, then how are we supposed to bend the mesh?

Comment: That's why I was suggesting using soft body simulations. I haven't seen any proof that this method works in this situation, but I would give it a try.
Otherwise you can use a lattice to deform multiple objects, (with a subdivision modifier above it in "simple" mode to have the objects bend properly, but I doubt this would be convincing on an animation.
Are you making a still image or an animation ?

Comment: @Gamnamno, I am currently only limited to still imaging. and I tried using soft body sim, the result has not been convincing, the bend can be done easily but the hardest part is making the splinters look convincing, like the actually sprout out of the mesh object.

Comment: ok, so since you're making a still, have you tried the lattice modifier ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have made this simple (but probably not perfect) wood splinter bending simulation with the blender fracture modifier.I used more and shorter splinters in the middle so the rubbery constraints let them atleast roughly look like bent longer splinters. 
The advantage of this being a modifier is you can just apply the mesh in the "bent" state and edit further if necessary. I also tried with a simple deform after fracture, but this did not look good at all...

The fracture modifier is a separate branch. Links to builds are here

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343637-Custom-Build-Blender-Fracture-Modifier

or here (latest windows build): http://graphicall.org/1148

Will upload a blend if I can find the "BlendExchange" button again somewhere... so for now just a pasteall link...

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44841

[image]

[image: wood splinter break]

Comment: there is no blend-exchange button; it's an external third-party website, found here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: ah yes, i was referring to answer 1 from here

Comment: here http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting ( i hit enter too early...)  and yes that has a userscript (was thinking i saw it built in already some time ago :)

Comment: Oopsy! I thought u were a new user u couldn't find that mysterious .blend button anywhere ;)